# Can libtorch be used for quantization-aware training of models?

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

We want to use C++ to develop a software for deep learning model training and quantification. For the convenience of deployment, we don't want to use python language, so we want to implement it based on libtorch.
I found the following example program for python-based quantization-aware training in pytorch's blog.

```
import torch
from torch import nn

backend = "fbgemm"  # running on a x86 CPU. Use "qnnpack" if running on ARM.

m = nn.Sequential(
     nn.Conv2d(2,64,8),
     nn.ReLU(),
     nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 8),
     nn.ReLU()
)

"""Fuse"""
torch.quantization.fuse_modules(m, ['0','1'], inplace=True) # fuse first Conv-ReLU pair
torch.quantization.fuse_modules(m, ['2','3'], inplace=True) # fuse second Conv-ReLU pair

"""Insert stubs"""
m = nn.Sequential(torch.quantization.QuantStub(), 
                  *m, 
                  torch.quantization.DeQuantStub())

"""Prepare"""
m.train()
m.qconfig = torch.quantization.get_default_qconfig(backend)
torch.quantization.prepare_qat(m, inplace=True)

"""Training Loop"""
n_epochs = 10
opt = torch.optim.SGD(m.parameters(), lr=0.1)
loss_fn = lambda out, tgt: torch.pow(tgt-out, 2).mean()
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
  x = torch.rand(10,2,24,24)
  out = m(x)
  loss = loss_fn(out, torch.rand_like(out))
  opt.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  opt.step()

"""Convert"""
m.eval()
torch.quantization.convert(m, inplace=True)
```

However, I did not find an example of quantization-aware training of models based on libtorch on the Internet.

I tried to refer to the quantization module in libtorch, but it was also wrong, as shown in the figure below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWvIo.png)

Does libtorch support quantization-aware training of models, and if so, are there any relevant examples?

Comment: Have you considered training in python and deployment in C++?

Comment: We want users to fine-tune the model by themselves. If use python, need to install the python runtime environment, which will be more troublesome.